# missing `typename` in gcc 11.1.0 ranges header

Tags: c++, c++20, libstdc++, std-ranges

I'm using `clang-12.0.1` and `libstdc++` from `gcc-11.1.0`. When including `<ranges>`, I get the following error:

```
[build] /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/ranges:3392:19: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'iterator_traits<iterator_t<_Base>>::iterator_category'
[build]             using _Cat = iterator_traits<iterator_t<_Base>>::iterator_category;
[build]                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is this a library bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang has not implemented [P0634R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html) yet, as per [the current posted status](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20).

So to answer your question:

> Is this a library bug?

Nope! Since the ranges library is only available in C++20, GCC's implementation is free to use syntax that is only available as per that version of the standard.

Comment: Cool, I remember that proposal but didn't check `clang`'s progress on it. Thanks!

Comment: It is worth noting that [the authors of libstdc++ are aware of this problem](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100900), but they do not have enough time to work around the entire `<ranges>`.